# Latex lstlisting emph

Tags: latex, lstlisting

I'm using lstlisting but noticed that it doesnt highlight any non alphanumeric characters like curly brackets and * and + etc?

\lstset{emph={abs,sqrt,{,::,.,-,+,*,},emphstyle={\color{darkred}}}

Comment: Please make a [mre]

Answer (score 0):

Can you try these lstlisting option `morekeywords` and `keywordstyle` in `lstset`

```
\lstset{morekeywords={abs,sqrt,{,::,.,-,+,*,}},keywordstyle={\itshape\color{red}}}
```